# Aurelia e2e: Check if span within a div contains certain text

Tags: node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I want to see if the text contained in a span which itself is contained in a div contains certain text.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="funds">
    <span>banking</span>
    <span class="m-l-sm">
        <b>EUR 1,000</b>
    </span><!--anchor-->
</div>
```

I want to check if `<span class="m-l-sm">` contains 'EUR'.

One way I tried to do this (among several others) is:

```
var checkFunds = element(by.id("m-l-sm"));
if (checkFunds.getText().toContain('EUR'&'GBP')) {
    //do something
}
```

I get an error saying `.toContain()` is not a function.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.toContain()` is a Jasmine matcher's method](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). It is usually used for assertions, e.g.:

```
expect(checkFunds.getText()).toContain('EUR');
```

Since it looks like you actually want to do something if you see a substring in a string - you need to get to the actual text of the element, which means you need to resolve the promise returned by `.getText()`. Then, you can check if substring `EUR` is inside the text:

```
var checkFunds = element(by.id("m-l-sm"));
checkFunds.getText().then(function (text) {
    if (text.indexOf('EUR') >= 0) {
        // do something
    }
});
```